# How to get parameters value in string from post url in rest api in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get parameters value in string from post url in rest api in magento 2.
(I need username and password in my custom module).
http://.../Magento2/index.php/rest/V1/authorize?username=Arjun&password=2.
I am getting o as value and not string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interface have you added docblock (/** /) This specifies what will be return type of your output and which is must? For my code I was just  adding sum of two numbers so here is code of my interface as below,

```
interface CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Add two numbers.
     *
     * @param int $num1
     * @param int $num2
     * @return int
     */
    public function add($num1, $num2);
}
```

Comment: Anytime :) You can upvote using up arrow if it helped you. Thanks :)